# Regex apostpophies

Tags: java, regex

I made a regex:

`\b\w+((\w'\b)|('\w\w\b)|(\w'\w\b))`

I am trying to match words like: `that's`, `you're`, and `something'`

My problem is that while this is matching, it is not matching the whole word.
`that's` is matching as `that'` as an example.

Please what am I doing wrong?

This is java.

Comment: `that'` and `something'` are in same case, aren't they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the order of your alternations.

The reason `that'` is matching is because your first alternation is `\w'\b`. If you changed your first one to `\w'\w\b` you should find that it will correctly match `that's` now.

You should [check out this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) for more information on alternations. Specifically the bottom section covers your issue.

Comment: With: `\b\w+(('\w\w\b)|(\w'\w\b)|(\w'\b))` I tested it and `something'` didn't match but everything else did. Why's that?

`This is a test. That's it a test. You're a dork. something' is a test.` 

http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: @user2001545 try `\b\w+(('\w\w\b)|(\w'\w\b)|(\w'(?!\w)))`

Comment: Yes thanks that works. So instead of a word boundary this is looking for a non word character after the apostrophe.

Comment: That would most likely be because there is no ending word boundary at the end of `something' ` since it is followed by an apostrophe and then a space. Both of those are considered non word characters.

Answer (score 0):

Why wont you use simple regex : ([a-zA-Z]*'[a-zA-Z]*)

---

#### Demo:

```
String str = " something' that's you're my";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]*'[a-zA-Z]*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
  String match = m.group();
  System.out.println(match);
}
```

See **[this demo](http://ideone.com/nSfnaY)**.